# R remove duplicates and aggregate sums in multiple columns

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm using R and trying to remove duplicates that already count occurrences for two columns. The actual data I'm working with is very large, so I'm trying to avoid using loops.

```
table <- data.table(set = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'c'), pred = c('p', 'p', 'p', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q'), setcount = 1:8, predcount = 9:2)

   set pred setcount predcount
1:   a    p        1         9
2:   b    p        2         8
3:   a    p        3         7
4:   d    q        4         6
5:   b    q        5         5
6:   d    q        6         4
7:   d    q        7         3
8:   c    q        8         2
```

What I'm starting with is this: where 'set' and 'pred' must both be the same to count as a duplicate - such as rows 1 and 3, and rows 4, 6, and 7.  When I remove these rows, I would like to sum the counts of the removed rows to achieve this:

```
   set pred setcount predcount
1:   a    p        4        16
2:   b    p        2         8
3:   b    q        5         5
4:   c    q        8         2
5:   d    q       17        13
```

Since I'm not very experienced in coding, what I've done so far has been as follows:

```
remove.Duplicates <- function(input, x, y, z, zz) {
            table <- input
            table <- arrange(table, x, y)
            table <- table[duplicated(table$x)&duplicated(table$y)|
                               duplicated(table$x, fromLast = T)&duplicated(table$y, fromLast = T),]
            table <- table[duplicated(table$y)|duplicated(table$y, fromLast = T),]
            table <- aggregate(z ~ .,table, sum)

            input <- input[input[, .I[!(duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast = T))], y]$V1]
            rbind(input, table)
        }
```

This worked fine when I only had the "setcount" (z) column, but I'm having difficulty aggregating the "predcount" (zz) column as well. The zz variable isn't in the code because I couldn't get it to run without any errors. The current code works, but only with a 3 column subset.

I'm sure that there is a much more efficient way to do this, but I'm at a loss for now. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to aggregate your data:

```
table[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by=list(set,pred)]
```